# NServiceBus & IIS

Tags: iis, nservicebus

`NSB 4.6.1
IIS 7.5 - Recyling for this pool is turned off`

I am hosting a handler inside of a IIS web appblication which forwards messages to web clients over SignalR. These messages are sent from other NSB services. The problem I run into is that in production the handler for these messages will randomly stop consuming messages from the queue and I have to restart iis to get it to start again. I can't reproduce this issue outside of production, and I cannot find any information in any of my logs.

Anyone have any ideas on what may be causing this?

My NSB configuration

`var bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
                      .StructureMapBuilder(container)
                      .UseTransport<Msmq>()
                      .UnicastBus()
                      .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                      .CreateBus();`

Comment: in [this sample](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Msmq.Samples/tree/master/VideoStore.Msmq) you can see the same scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try to configure IIS as always running and see if the behavior changes?
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677261(v=azure.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677261%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

.m